# Send Http Request at user set time (python back end)

Tags: javascript, python

Hi I'm trying to achieve a http request sent at the time variable set by the user.

This function will set of a chain of events such as comparing the received http responce with json string and possibly sending a further HTTP request depending on the outcome.

This is easy done in javascript but im having difficulty doing this server side e.g. web app in offline mode.

The current setup is messy. I'm rewriting this from scratch atm, so my question is;
Can this be achieved with scheduler or will a cron task need to be used, i have no experience using cron. Essentially i need a server side function to be executed at the set time, try googling it and you get alsorts of non-related items, can anyone point out whats actually required to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule) is what you need. It's an elegant python library for job scheduling. An example would be like this:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)
schedule.every().monday.do(job)
schedule.every().wednesday.at("13:15").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import datetime

while True:
    dt1 = datetime.datetime.now()
    dt2 = ...  # datetime of next action
    # Time to next action
    dif = dt2 - dt1
    # Wait for next action
    time.sleep(dif.total_seconds())
```